# Reversible hash type algo?

Tags: php

Odd question...but I need a private key encryption (or complex enough encoding) that outputs 64 random characters - given a string of 30 characters.

Blowfish or similar seems over kill and would probably not produce the fixed 64 byte result...also I'm less concerned with security more concerned with tampering - so a simple encoding scheme like rot13 won't suffice.

Short of using something like blowfish or building from scratch...

Any existing code I could pull from?

I guess I could pad the 30 char with the remaining 34 then basically I have to scramble all the chars -preferably using a private key.

Any existing packagist project I could use???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not looking for something completely solid and cryptographically strong, you may just use RC4 algorithm with shared secret.

The implementation is here, for example - https://gist.github.com/farhadi/2185197

As for making the output exactly 64 bytes long - what's wrong with padding?

Comment: I could just add padding to the original text...yes but does the encryption not add to the size?

Comment: RC4 doesn't change the length of encrypted string. However, be careful if you're saving it in database or in some text files. The encrypted string may not contain valid ASCII characters and may get corrupted if transferred via transport that expects UTF-8 strings. For this reason you might want to use base64 on encrypted string and this will increase the length.